# How to activate a component by conditons in Nestjs

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I have a question here. How to activate service by env variables or profile(a concept in Spring)? Eg. I have a DataInitializer (using `@Injectable`) service which is for inserting some data when the application is starting.

```js
@Injectable()
export class PostDataInitializerService implements OnModuleInit, OnModuleDestroy {
  private data: CreatePostDto[] = [
    {
      title: 'Generate a NestJS project',
      content: 'content',
    },
    {
      title: 'Create CRUD RESTful APIs',
      content: 'content',
    },
    {
      title: 'Connect to MongoDB',
      content: 'content',
    },
  ];

  constructor(private postService: PostService) {}
  onModuleInit(): void {
    console.log('(PostModule) is initialized...');
    this.data.forEach(d => {
      this.postService.save(d).subscribe(saved => console.log(saved));
    });
  }
  onModuleDestroy(): void {
    console.log('(PostModule) is being destroyed...');
    this.postService
      .deleteAll()
      .subscribe(del => console.log(`deleted ${del.deletedCount} rows`));
  }
}
```

but I want to **disable the service**(do not need this service) in a production env, how to archive this purpose?

Comment: Can you help me understand what will be the use case where some service is needed in local/staging and not production?

Comment: Created  issue [#4927](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/4927)